# bases de datos en wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Soy novato en wordpress y quisiera haceros una consulta y de paso me echárais una mano. Tengo una página en html que me funciona pero que no tengo ni idea de cómo hacerlo en wordpress. El tema es el siguiente, tengo un formulario en el que me debe de consultar los datos del cliente e insertarlos si éste no existe. Qué plugin puedo usar o como lo puedo hacer? La base de datos es la propia de wordpress, no es externa. Gracias por todo y vuestra ayuda

Comment: *que plugin puedo usar* te recomiendo quitar este fragmento de tu pregunta. Las preguntas que buscan recomendaciones de recursos externos (como plugins) terminan cerradas, ya que atraen respuestas basadas en opiniones, las cuales no encajan con el sitio.

Comment: Otra recomendación que te doy es agregar un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) y/o lo que investigaste hasta ahora. Por favor lee [como preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)